# If $f\left(\dfrac{2 \tan x}{1+\tan^2x}\right)=\left(\cos 2x+1\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{\sec^2x+2\tan x}{2}\right)$ then the domain of $f(x)$ is?

Tags: functions

> If $f\left(\dfrac{2 \tan x}{1+\tan^2x}\right)=\left(\cos 2x+1\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{\sec^2x+2\tan x}{2}\right)$
> then domain of $f(x)$ is?

**Teacher's Statement:** 
Domain is $\left[-1,1\right]$, because $\dfrac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}=\sin(2x)$ and $\sin(2x) $ varies from $ \left[-1,1\right]$.

**My doubt:** 
Since domain is generally value of $x$ so according to me the domain should be $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{\dfrac{(2n+1 )\pi}{2}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$.

Comment: What is $R-\frac{(2n+1)\pi}2$?

Comment: $x$ belongs to Real number excluding odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Then you should have written $\Bbb R\setminus\left\{\frac{(2n+1)\pi}2\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb Z\right\}$.

Comment: thanks, I'll take care of that next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the teacher is right.

Define $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{2 \tan x}{1+\tan^2x}.$

The way that the function $f$ is defined, it will only *operate* on numbers that are in the **range** of $g(x)$.

For example, consider $x = 5.$

Per the definition of $f$, f(5) **is not defined**, while $f[g(5)]$ **is defined**.

Therefore, the domain of $f$ equals the range of $g$.

Comment: Also need to check that for any $x$ in the range of $g$, the number $f(x)$ is actually defined.